# Failed to download metadata for repo 'powertools': Cannot download repomd.xml

Tags: centos, kde-plasma, centos8

I want to enable Powertools on Centos 8 for installing KDE.
But i get this error:

````
``` 
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'powertools':
  - Status code: 403 for http://vault.centos.org/centos/8/PowerTools/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 172.19.93.163)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'powertools': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried ```
````

My /etc/yum.repos.d/ looks like this :
[image]

and my Powertools repo file looks lke this :

````
```  CentOS-Linux-PowerTools.repo
#
# The ###mirrorlist system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick current mirrors that are geographically
# close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates unless you are
# manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the ###mirrorlist does not work for you, you can try the commented out
# baseurl line instead.
[powertools]
name=CentOS Linux $releasever - PowerTools
###mirrorlist=http://###mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=PowerTools&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/PowerTools/$basearch/os/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial
~
~
~
~ ```
````

i changed the base URL to the one pointing to vault. I understood that it has something to do with Centos 8 reaching end of life in 2021. I ran these commands:

```
# sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
# sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
```

and

```
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-*
sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.epel.cloud|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-*
```

I would just need a valid url where to install the powertools . Is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a working solution:

1. I installed a Virtual Box with the same Linux image
2. I copied the repo files from the virtualbox image and replaced the ones on my current VM. I did this because i wanted a reset for the repo files.
   3.(most important step) I migrated to Rocky Linux . This is a fork of Centos 8. Works exactly how it should. It's basically like a Centos with working repo's.

Rocky Linux has good documentations and it just works.

Comment: Hi, Can you share with us the repo files mirrorlist url